# How is the +++ escape sequence for modems supposed to work?

Tags: linux, communication, at-command, modem, ppp

I would like to be able to suspend a current modem PPP connection, and go into a mode where I can enter AT commands, then resume the PPP connection.

I had heard that this was possible by waiting a second, sending three '+' characters in quick succession, then waiting another second.  I cannot get it to work however, I never enter command mode.  Can anyone let me know what the exact procedure is?

It is not clear to me how one would send the pause, then the "+++" then the trailer pause while pppd has a lock on the modem port.  pppd itself does not seem to support this escaping feature.

Comment: Are you sure your modem supports this?

Comment: Apparently it does yes.